# Magento 2 product image is visible in Magento admin, but not visible in frontend

Tags: magento2.3

Magento 2 product image is visible in Magento admin, but not visible in frontend.
i have try all these solutions but no luck.

Magento version (2.3.6)

Frontend Preview: https://postimg.cc/xkK3Gts8

> Solution 1 - 777 permissions to the media folder
> https://postimg.cc/fkxhSgP1
>
> Solution 2 - Ownership of the media folder
> https://postimg.cc/rKjXQRMJ
>
> Solution 3 - Low PHP memory limit.
> https://postimg.cc/w1BKPxBd
>
> Solution 4 - already GD library is installed/configured.
> https://postimg.cc/87n8V8Ff
>
> Solution 5 - Set Global attribute scope for small_image, thumbnail,
> base_image
> https://postimg.cc/Lqrrnz3H
> https://postimg.cc/DWW9vCsj
> https://postimg.cc/rKM21NXs
>
> Solution 6 -  Rename the original .htaccess file in the media folder
>
> https://postimg.cc/hQbWFfxK

**Can anyone save me from here?

Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command:

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

**Hope so it will solve your issue..if not do let me know**

Comment: Thanks for your time and try to find solutions but Once I used this command it works for old products but when I upload new products again same issue. and yes I have more than 25k products uploaded so it's take a whole day or more. so it's not a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
Replace `Option FollowSymLinks` with `Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` in `pub/media/.htaccess` file and `pub/.htaccess` file.

Ref: https://www.integerbyteblog.in/magento/magento2-option-followsymlinks-not-allowed-here/

**Solution 2:**

Clear Catalog image cache

```
Admin -> System ->Cache Management -> Flush Catalog Images Cache
```

Then run folowwing command

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
php bin/magento c:f
```